# Merging 2 tables from two different datasets SQL Using Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, etl

Doing a project and have been stuck.

The two datasets are called mimic3_demo (c) and mimic3_demo_omop (m).

I need to merge one table from c to one table from m. The first table from dataset c is PATIENTS and the second table from dataset m is condition_occurrence.

I'd like to join them on SUBJECT_ID from database c table PATIENTS and person_id from database m table condition_occurrence.

This is the simple code I've used so far but it keeps saying "there is no data to display"

I am using Google Big Query to code this was what the course provided us.

```
Select *  
from mimic3_demo.dbo.PATIENTS c  
Join mimic3_demo_omop.dbo.condition_occurrence m on c.SUBJECT_ID = m.person_id
```

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: can you select * from each table by itself to make sure they have data?  can you spot-check subject_id and person_id to make sure they're similar data type and look for values in common?

Comment: They have data and they are both integer data types so that matches up. The only thing is they don't have values in common but the project specifically asks to merge these two variables. Is there any way to merge the two variables into one that lists all of their values instead of just the matching values?

Comment: if there's no values in common then perhaps they don't represent the same thing.  are there any other person/patient/subject ids available to join on?  you can do a full outer join to get all the records from both tables into one data set, but you will have a lot of null values since there are no matching values on these ids